# Curl suppress output when supplying header

Tags: bash, shell, curl

This suppresses the output and just outputs the status:

```
curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent --output /dev/null --noproxy '*' http://www.google.com/
```

Adding a header makes the entire response print:

```
curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent --output /dev/null --noproxy '*' --header ''"'"'Host:' '192.168.0.1:2345'"'" http://www.google.com/
```

How can I stop the output printing to stdout when injecting a header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at your command. Below invocation will write each separate argument in a new line.

```
$ printf '%q\n' curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent --output /dev/null --noproxy '*' --header ''"'"'Host:' '192.168.0.1:2345'"'" http://www.google.com/
curl
--write-out
%\{http_code\}
--silent
--output
/dev/null
--noproxy
\*
--header
\'Host:
192.168.0.1:2345\'
http://www.google.com/
```

Bingo, though `Host: 192.168.0.1:2345` must be a single argument, you're providing it to curl as two separate arguments, so it tries to fetch `192.168.0.1:2345'` first. And since `--output` is applied to only one URL, the response from `http://www.google.com/` is printed.

Do it like this and it'll work.

```
curl --write-out '%{http_code}\n' --silent --output /dev/null --noproxy '*' --header 'Host: 192.168.0.1:2345' http://www.google.com/
```

Comment: Thanks. Had some funky escaping going on and didn't pick up on it when copy and pasting from the log.  Had some ugly offset slicing going on to fix it